# Вопрос про input и PHP

Tags: php

Есть корзина товаров, где динамически выводятся все товары, которые посетитель добавил в корзину, а также цена товара, input для ввода количества товара и сумма. Вопрос - какой атрибут name мне нужно задать инпуту, чтобы на сервер приходил массив значений?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ух. Простите но я не совсем понял. Но постараюсь объяснить.

Допустим у вас есть форма с с несколькими input'ами (а так вроде и есть). Так вот каждому из них нужно задать атрибут name примерно такого вида:

```
name="Product_meta[name]"
name="Product_meta[price]"
name="Product_meta[count]"
```

Ну а на сервере массив можно получить так:

```
$product_meta_array = $_POST["Product_meta"]; //допустим что данные были отправлены методом POST
```

Вообщем-то всё. В массиве $product_meta_array у вас будут такие элементы как name, price и count вместе с переданными значениями

Answer (score 6):

Если правильно понял, то name[]. Пример `<input name='pole[]' type='text' />`

Comment: А как на сервере получить этот массив?

Comment: Ну если на сервере, значит метод получение северный. Например через PHP `$_GET['pole']` - это массив.

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть можете использовать функцию print_r()